# What's kind of tree it is?

Tags: identification, trees

**Location**: Northern China
**Height**: I guess it's over 15m, about 20m.
**Note**: All leaves would fall out in the winter.

[image: The leaf]
[image: The trunk and the bark]

Comment: Does the tree produce any type of fruit in the form of seed capsules, and do you have another example of a leaf or two please to account for variation between leaves? The bark looks like Betula pendula, but the leaf's not quite right

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! @Bamboo, @stormy, @Stephie
I have known it.
It's **Populus alba**.
See here → [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_alba)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Alnus rubra or Red Alder.  A very tough tree.

Comment: Wrong leaf shape. Yes to *Betulaceae*, though. Thanks for mentioning this fascinating tree, I learned something new!